# javascript load html inside html

Tags: javascript, html

How to load HTML file from another HTML file using javascript and not JQuery?

I have seen couple of examples using jquery .load function but I need to know how can we load html file using simple javascript.

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far

Comment: They use jQuery because you need to do an AJAX call and jQuery gives you an easy way to do that. If you don't do that, you will have to build your own AJAX call. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery you have an example here.

Comment: @harsha Have seen jquery using like this. $("head").load("sample.html"); But don't know how javascript uses it.

Comment: Jquery is "simple javascript" it's just a library that uses javascript underneath. Why can't you just reference the jquery files?

Comment: All.. This is a typical situation that not all my clients will use jquery in there pages. I will be added the jqeury script in the loading HTML. From then only I can get access to jquery. @DaGLiMiOuX: Thanks for the reply. That actually can be explained how to get the file. Few changes from that script works for me

Answer (score 1):

jQuery load function is a simple wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest` object that loads content using the specified url and places it into the matched element. So, your example `$("head").load("sample.html");` loads the content of the sample.html page and places it into the `head` tag.

In order to do this without jQuery you need to create `XMLHttpRequest` object directly. The exact code depends on the browsers you are targeting, but you can find a lot of examples online. A good place to start is [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started
and on readyState == 4 the request is completed. A successful request results in a HTTP 200 message:

```
if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
  if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
```

These are the guarding clauses, which check the result subsequentially. 
After both checks pass, you could append your result (httpRequest.responseXML) to the DOM.